# how can I have more than one y axis in keynote chart?

Tags: iwork-keynote

I want to be able to plot two lines in a chart in keynote presentation.

The two lines have different scaling. The x axis is the same, but the y axis of each line is different. Is it possible to plot a chart with two y axes, one on the left and one on the right, in keynote?

The data looks something like this:

```
X 10   20  30  40
Y1 0.5 0.9 1.2 1.5
Y2 100 50  30  21
```

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your chart and select **Chart Type** > **2-Axis**

Or initially before creating a chart, select the chart type at the bottom that looks like a bar and line chart together with ticks on both the left and right.

This creates a dual Y-axis chart and now the Series and Axis details in the chart Inspector show more details. By default the chart will have 1 line and multiple bars, and you can select a series and in the inspector and change the bars to lines by clicking on **Series Type** > **Line**. You also have options in the inspector for which axis to plot on.

In the past, I have used Excel to create a chart with two y-axis, then copy and paste it in to Keynote. Not as beautiful and simple, but does the job. To do this in in Excel Mac 2011, after you have plotted all your data series in a chart, right click on a single series, select **Format Data Series** > **Axis** > **Plot Series on Secondary Axis**.

Comment: This option does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The right click option is no longer available in Keynote 6. However, the 2-axis type can be chosen when creating the chart or from the Chart Type popup in the Chart format panel.

Comment: I see no option to choose that in Keynote 8.

Answer (score 1):

Keynote 8 and above has gotten rid of `Chart Type` in the right-click menu, but you can still select the chart and go to `Format -> Chart -> Chart Type -> 2-D 2-Axis` to do what Ryan said above.